# Keyestudio KS5009 ESP32WROOM32 Smart Home

Tags: esp32, library, functions, home-automation

I'm encountering persistent errors with the sample code provided for my smart home kit project. Despite conducting extensive research and troubleshooting efforts, I haven't been able to find a solution. It's becoming increasingly frustrating as each problem I fix seems to be replaced by another. I'd greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this ongoing issue.

```cpp
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <ESPmDNS.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#define LED_PIN    26
// How many NeoPixels are attached to the Arduino?
#define LED_COUNT 4
// Declare our NeoPixel strip object:
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

String item = "0";
const char* ssid = "Temp_Wifi"; //Wifi Name 
const char* password = "Temp4"; //Wifif Password
WiFiServer server(80);

#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C mylcd(0x27,16,2);
#include <analogWrite.h>
#include "xht11.h"
xht11 xht(17);
//#include <ESP32_Servo.h>
//Servo Wservo;
//Servo Dservo;
#include <ESP32Tone.h>
#define buzzer_pin 25
//#define windowServo 5
//#define doorServo 13
#define waterPin 34
#define fanPin1 19
#define fanPin2 18
#define led_y 12  //Define the yellow led pin to 12

#define waterPin 34
#define gasPin 23
#define pyroelectric 14

unsigned char dht[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};//Only the first 32 bits of data are received, not the parity bits

//Servo channel
int channel_PWM = 13;
int channel_PWM2 = 10;
int freq_PWM = 50; 
int resolution_PWM = 10;
const int PWM_Pin1 = 5;
const int PWM_Pin2 = 13;




void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  mylcd.init();
  mylcd.backlight();
  pinMode(led_y, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(fanPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(fanPin2, OUTPUT);
  ledcSetup(5, 1200, 8);//Set the frequency of LEDC channel 1 to 1200 and PWM resolution to 8, that is duty cycle to 256.  
  ledcAttachPin(fanPin2, 5);  //Bind the LEDC channel 1 to the specified left motor pin GPIO26 for output.  
  pinMode(waterPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(buzzer_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(gasPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(pyroelectric, INPUT);
  ledcSetup(channel_PWM, freq_PWM, resolution_PWM); //Set servo channel and frequency as well as PWM resolution.
  ledcSetup(channel_PWM2, freq_PWM, resolution_PWM);
  ledcAttachPin(PWM_Pin1, channel_PWM);  //Binds the LEDC channel to the specified IO port for output
  ledcAttachPin(PWM_Pin2, channel_PWM2);  //Binds the LEDC channel to the specified IO port for output
//  Wservo.attach(windowServo);
//  Dservo.attach(doorServo);
//  #if defined(__AVR_ATtiny85__) && (F_CPU == 16000000)
//    clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1);
//  #endif
//    // END of Trinket-specific code.
//  strip.begin();           // INITIALIZE NeoPixel strip object (REQUIRED)
//  strip.show();            // Turn OFF all pixels ASAP
//  strip.setBrightness(50); // Set BRIGHTNESS to about 1/5 (max = 255)
  
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("TCP server started");
  MDNS.addService("http", "tcp", 80);
  mylcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  mylcd.print("ip:");
  mylcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  mylcd.print(WiFi.localIP());  //LCD displays ip adress
}

void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
      return;
  }
  while(client.connected() && !client.available()){
      delay(1);
  }
  String req = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  int addr_start = req.indexOf(' ');
  int addr_end = req.indexOf(' ', addr_start + 1);
  if (addr_start == -1 || addr_end == -1) {
      Serial.print("Invalid request: ");
      Serial.println(req);
      return;
  }
  req = req.substring(addr_start + 1, addr_end);
  item=req;
  Serial.println(item);
  String s;
  if (req == "/")  //Browser accesses address can read the information sent by the client.println(s);
  {
      IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
      String ipStr = String(ip[0]) + '.' + String(ip[1]) + '.' + String(ip[2]) + '.' + String(ip[3]);
      s = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n<html>ESP32 ip:";
      s += ipStr;
      s += "</html>\r\n\r\n";
      Serial.println("Sending 200");
      client.println(s);  //Send the string S, then you can read the information when visiting the address of E smart home using the browser.
  }
  if(req == "/led/on") //Browser accesses address ip address/led/on
  {
    client.println("turn on the LED");
    digitalWrite(led_y, HIGH);
  }
  if(req == "/led/off") //Browser accesses address ip address/led/off
  {
    client.println("turn off the LED");
    digitalWrite(led_y, LOW);
  }
  if(req == "/window/on")
  {
    client.println("open the window");
    ledcWrite(channel_PWM, 100);  //The high level of 20ms is about 2.5ms, that is, 2.5/20*1024, at this time, the servo angle is 180°.  
    //Wservo.write(175);
  }
  if(req == "/window/off")
  {
    client.println("close the window");
    ledcWrite(channel_PWM, 60);  //The high level of 20ms is about 0.5ms，that is, 0.5/20*1024，at this time, the servo angle is 0°.
    //Wservo.write(0);
  }
  if(req == "/music/on")
  {
    //client.println("play music");
  }
  if(req == "/music/off")
  {
    client.println("play music");
    birthday();
    noTone(buzzer_pin,0);
  }
  if(req == "/buz/on")
  {
    client.println("buzzer");
    tone(buzzer_pin,392,250,0);
    Serial.println("1");
  }
  if(req == "/buz/off")
  {
    client.println("off");
    noTone(buzzer_pin,0);
  }
  if(req == "/door/on")
  {
    client.println("open the door");
    ledcWrite(channel_PWM2, 120);
//    Dservo.write(180);
  }
  if(req == "/door/off")
  {
    client.println("close the door");
     ledcWrite(channel_PWM2, 20);
//    Dservo.write(0);
  }
  if(req == "/fan/on")
  {
    client.println("turn on the fan");
    digitalWrite(fanPin1, LOW); //pwm = 0
    ledcWrite(5, 100); //The LEDC channel 1 is bound to the specified left motor output PWM value of 100.
  }
  if(req == "/fan/off")
  {
    client.println("turn off the fan");
    digitalWrite(fanPin1, LOW); //pwm = 0
    ledcWrite(5, 0); //The LEDC channel 1 is bound to the specified left motor output PWM value of 0.
  }
  if(req == "/red/on")
  {
    client.println("red on");
    colorWipe(strip.Color(255,   0,   0), 50);
  }
  if(req == "/red/off")
  {
    client.println("red off");
    colorWipe(strip.Color(0,   0,   0), 50);
  }
  if(req == "/oringe/on")
  {
    client.println("oringe on");
    colorWipe(strip.Color(200,   100,   0), 50);
  }
  if(req == "/oringe/off")
  {
    client.println("oringe off");
    colorWipe(strip.Color(0,   0,   0), 50);
  }
  if(req == "/yellow/on")
  {
    client.println("yellow on");
    colorWipe(strip.Color(200,   200,   0), 50);
  }
  if(req == "/yellow/off")
  {
    client.println("yellow off");
    colorWipe(strip.Color(0,   0,   0), 50);
  }
  if(req == "/green/on")
  {
    client.println("green on");
    colorWipe(strip.Color(0,   255,   0), 50);
  }
  if(req == "/green/off")
  {
    client.println("green off");
    colorWipe(strip.Color(0,   0,   0), 50);
  }
  if(req == "/cyan/on")
  {
    client.println("cyan on");
    colorWipe(strip.Color(0,   100,   255), 50);
  }
  if(req == "/cyan/off")
  {
    client.println("cyan off");
    colorWipe(strip.Color(0,   0,   0), 50);
  }
  if(req == "/blue/on")
  {
    client.println("blue on");
    colorWipe(strip.Color(0,   0,   255), 50);
  }
  if(req == "/blue/off")
  {
    client.println("blue off");
    colorWipe(strip.Color(0,   0,   0), 50);
  }
  if(req == "/purple/on")
  {
    client.println("purple on");
    colorWipe(strip.Color(100,   0,   255), 50);
  }
  if(req == "/purple/off")
  {
    client.println("purple off");
    colorWipe(strip.Color(0,   0,   0), 50);
  }
  if(req == "/white/on")
  {
    client.println("white on");
    colorWipe(strip.Color(255,   255,   255), 50);
  }
  if(req == "/white/off")
  {
    client.println("white off");
    colorWipe(strip.Color(0,   0,   0), 50);
  }
  if(req == "/sfx1/on")
  {
    client.println("sfx1 on");
    rainbow(10);
  }
  if(req == "/sfx1/off")
  {
    client.println("sfx1 off");
    colorWipe(strip.Color(0,   0,   0), 50);
  }
  if(req == "/sfx2/on")
  {
    client.println("sfx2 on");
    theaterChaseRainbow(50);
  }
  if(req == "/sfx2/off")
  {
    client.println("sfx2 off");
    colorWipe(strip.Color(0,   0,   0), 50);
  }


  if(req == "/rain/on")
  {
    int rainVal = analogRead(waterPin);
    client.println(rainVal);
  }
  if(req == "/rain/off")
  {
    client.println("off");
  }
  if(req == "/gas/on")
  {
    boolean gasVal = analogRead(gasPin);
    if(gasVal == 0)
    {
      client.println("safety");
    }
    else
    {
      client.println("dangerous");
    }
  }
  if(req == "/gas/off")
  {
    client.println("off");
  }
  if(req == "/body/on")
  {
    boolean pyroelectric_val = digitalRead(pyroelectric);
    if(pyroelectric_val == 1)
    {
      client.println("someone");
    }
    else
    {
      client.println("no one");
    }
  }
  if(req == "/body/off")
  {
    client.println("off");
  }
  if(req == "/temp/on")
  {
    if (xht.receive(dht)) { //Returns true when checked correctly
      Serial.print("Temp:");
      Serial.print(dht[2]); //The integral part of temperature, DHT [3] is the fractional part
      Serial.println("C");
      delay(200);
    } else {    //Read error
      Serial.println("sensor error");
    }
    client.println(dht[2]);
    delay(1000);  //It takes 1000ms to wait for the device to read
  }
  if(req == "/temp/off")
  {
    client.println("off");
  }
  if(req == "/humidity/on")
  {
    if (xht.receive(dht)) { //Returns true when checked correctly
      Serial.print("Temp:");
      Serial.print(dht[0]); //The integral part of temperature, DHT [3] is the fractional part
      Serial.println("%");
      delay(200);
    } else {    //Read error
      Serial.println("sensor error");
    }
    client.println(dht[0]);
    delay(1000);  //It takes 1000ms to wait for the device to read
  }
  if(req == "/humidity/off")
  {
    client.println("off");
  }

  
  //client.stop();
}


void birthday()
{
  tone(buzzer_pin,294,250,0);  //The four parameters are pin, frequency, delay and channel 
  tone(buzzer_pin,440,250,0);
  tone(buzzer_pin,392,250,0);
  tone(buzzer_pin,532,250,0);
  tone(buzzer_pin,494,250,0);
  tone(buzzer_pin,392,250,0);
  tone(buzzer_pin,440,250,0);
  tone(buzzer_pin,392,250,0);
  tone(buzzer_pin,587,250,0);
  tone(buzzer_pin,532,250,0);
  tone(buzzer_pin,392,250,0);
  tone(buzzer_pin,784,250,0);
  tone(buzzer_pin,659,250,0);
  tone(buzzer_pin,532,250,0);
  tone(buzzer_pin,494,250,0);
  tone(buzzer_pin,440,250,0);
  tone(buzzer_pin,698,250,0);
  tone(buzzer_pin,659,250,0);
  tone(buzzer_pin,532,250,0);
  tone(buzzer_pin,587,250,0);
  tone(buzzer_pin,532,500,0);
  noTone(buzzer_pin,0);  //关闭
}

void colorWipe(uint32_t color, int wait) {
  for(int i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) { // For each pixel in strip...
    strip.setPixelColor(i, color);         //  Set pixel's color (in RAM)
    strip.show();                          //  Update strip to match
    delay(wait);                           //  Pause for a moment
  }
}

// Rainbow cycle along whole strip. Pass delay time (in ms) between frames.
void rainbow(int wait) {
  for(long firstPixelHue = 0; firstPixelHue < 5*65536; firstPixelHue += 256) {
    for(int i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) { // For each pixel in strip...
      int pixelHue = firstPixelHue + (i * 65536L / strip.numPixels());
      strip.setPixelColor(i, strip.gamma32(strip.ColorHSV(pixelHue)));
    }
    strip.show(); // Update strip with new contents
    delay(wait);  // Pause for a moment
  }
}

// Rainbow-enhanced theater marquee. Pass delay time (in ms) between frames.
void theaterChaseRainbow(int wait) {
  int firstPixelHue = 0;     // First pixel starts at red (hue 0)
  for(int a=0; a<30; a++) {  // Repeat 30 times...
    for(int b=0; b<3; b++) { //  'b' counts from 0 to 2...
      strip.clear();         //   Set all pixels in RAM to 0 (off)
      // 'c' counts up from 'b' to end of strip in increments of 3...
      for(int c=b; c<strip.numPixels(); c += 3) {
        int      hue   = firstPixelHue + c * 65536L / strip.numPixels();
        uint32_t color = strip.gamma32(strip.ColorHSV(hue)); // hue -> RGB
        strip.setPixelColor(c, color); // Set pixel 'c' to value 'color'
      }
      strip.show();                // Update strip with new contents
      delay(wait);                 // Pause for a moment
      firstPixelHue += 65536 / 90; // One cycle of color wheel over 90 frames
    }
  }
}
```

The current error code I'm encountering during compilation is as follows:

```
WARNING: library LiquidCrystal_I2C claims to run on avr architecture(s) and may be incompatible with your current board which runs on esp32 architecture(s).
In file included from C:\Users\temp\Downloads\KS5009 Keyestudio Smart Home Kit for ESP32\3. Arduino Tutorials\arduino Code\pj13_2_IoT_smart_home\pj13_2_IoT_smart_home.ino:16:
c:\Users\temp\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.h:44:5: error: 'i2c_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'ino_t'?
     i2c_t * i2c;
     ^~~~~
     ino_t
c:\Users\temp\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.h:64:5: error: 'i2c_err_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'esp_err_t'?
     i2c_err_t last_error; // @stickBreaker from esp32-hal-i2c.h
     ^~~~~~~~~
     esp_err_t
c:\Users\temp\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.h:87:5: error: 'i2c_err_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'esp_err_t'?
     i2c_err_t writeTransmission(uint16_t address, uint8_t* buff, uint16_t size, bool sendStop=true);
     ^~~~~~~~~
     esp_err_t
c:\Users\temp\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.h:88:5: error: 'i2c_err_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'esp_err_t'?
     i2c_err_t readTransmission(uint16_t address, uint8_t* buff, uint16_t size, bool sendStop=true, uint32_t *readCount=NULL);
     ^~~~~~~~~
     esp_err_t
Multiple libraries were found for "Wire.h"
  Used: C:\Users\temp\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Wire
  Not used: C:\Users\temp\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.13\libraries\Wire
exit status 1

Compilation error: exit status 1
```

Comment: always format messages as code, so that they are readable here

Comment: why are you using the `avr` tag? ... you are not using an avr device

Comment: Why do you have a second Wire library in your libraries folder? May it be, that this library version does not support the ESP32? Try removing that Wire library from your libraries foldern so that the IDE will use the version that comes with your ESP core

Comment: I deleted the Wire library, but I'm still receiving error codes like the ones above with addition to wire.h not being declared error.